# aws s3a read is ok but facing errors with write operation

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am using spark 2.4 and I am running spark app in ec2. I am able to read but not write to s3.

I have `/opt/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar` and `/opt/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar` in classpath.
I am able to read s3 files but write gives AWS Error Message:

```
Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: XXXXXXXXX
```

I got the same error too for reading, then I removed access keys from spark properties and managed s3 access via roles and it worked. S3 Policy gives full permission on bucket--*

```
ppl10.write.format("csv").mode("Overwrite").save("s3a://mybucket/data/proto_ds_out")
```

Detail error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
Status Code: 403, 
AWS Service: Amazon S3, 
AWS Request ID: 5E4B3CE8F0940E35, 
AWS Error Code: null, 
AWS Error Message: Forbidden, 
S3 Extended Request ID: Mq6rwJGff8UONQHsBU+mlIggUCUyUYuzYOtyCj7o/7icK6FDw/y9plPkHgwpBUbedUwFIE0eTsU=
```

Comment: Make sure you have read and write permission. Seems to me you have read only permission wherever you're trying to write.

Comment: s3 bucket has full permissions ...

Comment: could also be the client or the bucket is set up use a KMS key you don't have permissions to

Comment: ok  even a public S3 bucket would only create the s3 folder but executors were not able to write.  What finally worked was to create policy with all Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*" and then assign this  to ec2 role . I know this may not be ideal but the error has no information as what specific aws service was causing issue,  as the Ec2 role already has all S3 RW permissions.  that was the only option i had to do